# How to return column header if a cell contain certain value based on their nth occurrence

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a table with delivery dates and number of package delivered to a person on a given date. Each person received package with different number of times.

I want to have another table to show when they get their 1st, 2nd and 3rd delivery and the amount of package they get on each delivery date.

[image]

I am using Office 2013.  After some Googling, I found that I can use this formula in Column M:
    =IF(COUNTA($B$3:$K$3)=0,"",INDEX($B$2:$K$2,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($B3:$K3<>"",0),0)))

[image]

Comment: Hi @Donna Feliciano ,, my very first question is that what is wrong with the Desire Results you have produce,, what is missing ? According to me your second Table must comprises NAME ,, DATE & No Of Deliveries

Comment: the desired result is filled manually. I can only find formula to produce column M, but not the rest of the other column. The second table supposedly to have column L as Name. thanks

Answer (score 0):

*This is the possible result,solves the issue:*

[image]

**N.B.**

- Suggested method works on single time execution.
- What you have entered manually needs the formula to execute for each delivery.

---

[image]

- Formula in cell `L131`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(IF(INDEX(B$131:$H$140,MATCH($J131,$A$131:$A$140,0),MATCH($K131,$B$130:$H$130,0))=0,"",INDEX(B$131:$H$140,MATCH($J131,$A$131:$A$140,0),MATCH($K131,$B$130:$H$130,0))),"")
  ```
- *You can modify the headers in `L130:R130`.*
- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Rajesh-S, I can produce desired table that looks like the one on my question, but I **still cannot find a formula to populate columns for the 2nd and 3rd delivery dates** (values in Column M & O is put manually).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcYLt.png)

I slightly modified formula from @Rajesh-s to populate columns for amount (L,N,P).

Formula in K131:
=IF(COUNTA($B131:$G131)=0,"",INDEX($B$130:$G$130,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($B131:$G131<>"",0),0)))

Formula in L131:
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX($B$131:$H$140,MATCH($J131,$J$131:$J$140,0),MATCH($K131,$B$130:$H$130,0))=0,"",INDEX($B$131:$H$140,MATCH($J131,$J$131:$J$140,0),MATCH($K131,$B$130:$H$130,0))),"")

Formula in N131
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX($B$131:$H$140,MATCH($J131,$J$131:$J$140,0),MATCH($M131,$B$130:$H$130,0))=0,"",INDEX($B$131:$H$140,MATCH($J131,$J$131:$J$140,0),MATCH($M131,$B$130:$H$130,0))),"")

Formula in P131
==IFERROR(IF(INDEX($B$131:$H$140,MATCH($J131,$J$131:$J$140,0),MATCH($O131,$B$130:$H$130,0))=0,"",INDEX($B$131:$H$140,MATCH($J131,$J$131:$J$140,0),MATCH($O131,$B$130:$H$130,0))),"")